# Is it possible to Web Browsing on CentOS Server?

Tags: centos5

i want to remote server for Web Browsing to restart my router is it possible?
if yes, could you tell me a solution ?

Comment: Please rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use elinks or lynx to browse to your router at a command line from you CentOS box. If elinks is not installed, just run yum install elinks. If you have X installed on your server you could also connect via VNC or a ssh tunneled X connection (ssh -X) but elinks should work and it is very easy to use.